# Checking if port is open

Tags: windows-server-2008, port, telnet

I want to see if port 1878 is open on my Windows Server 2008 R2.
I use VPS server, so i talked with the VPS servers company and asked them to open all ports.

When i'm running telnet 172.0.0.1 1878 i get that the port is not reachable.
Is there another way to see if the port is open or open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use may use software such as **nMap** to test if a port is working, more specifically if it is closed or open.

You may have to add the -Pn tag incase the port is hidden.

http://nmap.org/

Use the CLI Command:nmap (IP) -p (port)

Or, you may use a **web based tool** to check it if your VPS is live.

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ STATES THAT PORT IS CLOSED - CAN IT BE? How can i open it?

Comment: what this means: Nmap scan report for IP

Host is up.

PORT     STATE   SERVICE

1878/tcp unknown privatearik



Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.24 seconds

Comment: Hmm.. That's weird. Asper nMap the port is open, but asper YouGetSignal it's closed.

Have you enabled telnet?
http://www.elmajdal.net/win2k8/how_to_enable_telnet_in_windows_server_2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true) to list out what is used and what isn't.  You could also download [netcat for windows](http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows), which effectively does the same as you trying telnet, it just has a command line option just to test if it can connect.  That would be something like:

> nc -z 127.0.0.1 1878

Comment: nc -z 127.0.0.1 1878 where? in netcat?

Comment: That would be the whole commandline you type.  nc is netcat (or at least is the netcat command on linux, it may be "netcat" on windows).  the rest are the command line options to have netcat attempt the connection.  It should then tell you if the port is open or closed.