# Find specific port using command prompt

Tags: php, cmd, port

Is it possible to find specific port using command prompt? I want to use the exec command in php to check if a port is open. The fsockopen function in php is very slow so i wanna try to use the cmd to check the port and see if that works better. I want to find if port 7878 is open.

I do not wish to download any softwares, I only want to know if it's possible to do it directly in cmd. And if its possible i want to know how the command for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if port is open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901157/checking-if-port-is-open)

Comment: No it's not because he use telnet and i do not wish to download any softwares

Comment: for a start, which os?

Comment: @user3055512 there is another answer on that question that applies netstat which is available with all Windows. Try that

Comment: do you need to check localhost port or any other external resources ports?

Answer (score 2):

i do not know about php code but in network we using : 
cmd->telnet [domainname or ip] [port]

i strogly recomended not to use exec in php and even[look here](https://support.mayfirst.org/ticket/6379)

so i  found this hope help you

[here (may be slower but safer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841635/how-to-ping-a-server-port-with-php)

Comment: But doesnt that requires to download telnet? I tried to use telnet in cmd and the command was not recognized

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netstat`:

```
netstat -na | find ":< port number >"
```

To find a foreign port you could use:

```
netstat -an | findstr ":N[^:]*$"
```

To find a local port you might use:

```
netstat -an | findstr ":N.*:[^:]*$"
```

Comment: Thanks. But that returns like 100 rows. If i use exec in php to echo this it will display all these rows on the page so it would be better if it would return "Open/Closed" or "Online/Offline" or "0/1" or something like that

Comment: @user3055512 Updated. Prepend ":" before port number to narrow your search results